# Is it possible to combine bounds of nested associated types?

Tags: rust, associated-types

I work with several traits that have associated types:

```
trait Foo {
    type FooType;
}

trait Bar {
    type BarType;
}

trait Baz {
    type BazType;
}
```

I have a function where I need to bound those associated types. I can do it like this ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=53f84c9c28ec9f9a2ebac47f5ff13313&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
fn do_the_thing<T>(_: T)
where
    T: Foo,
    T::FooType: Bar,
    <T::FooType as Bar>::BarType: Baz,
    <<T::FooType as Bar>::BarType as Baz>::BazType: Clone,
{}
```

This works, but it's very verbose. One problem is that I need to use the `<Type as Trait>` syntax to disambiguate a few paths, although that shouldn't be necessary. This issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38078).

I wonder if it's possible to shorten the definition of the above function. I thought, maybe it's possible to combine all bounds into one:

```
fn do_the_thing<T>(_: T)
where
    T: Foo<FooType: Bar<BarType: Baz<BazType: Clone>>>,
{}
```

But this results in a syntax error:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `,`, `::`, `<`, or `>`, found `:`
  --> src/main.rs:16:19
   |
16 |     T: Foo<FooType: Bar<BarType: Baz<BazType: Clone>>>,
   |                   ^ expected one of 7 possible tokens here
```

**Is there a way to compress the bounds somehow?**

Comment: Not compressible now, but there's an open RFC for this. https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible with the **unstable feature `associated_type_bounds`** ([tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662)).

```rust
#![feature(associated_type_bounds)]

fn do_the_thing<T>(_: T)
where
    T: Foo<FooType: Bar<BarType: Baz<BazType: Clone>>>,
{}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2a3c241c77174e3716bdcc9682f51c69))